# Increment count if the object exists in arraylist, else Add the object into arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner, equals

I read words from a text file and then create a new `Word` object for each word and store the objects into an `ArrayList`. The text of the word is passed into the object as a parameter. I have overridden the `equals(Object)` and `hashCode()` method of the word class to check for the equality of objects based on text of a word instead of object memory location. I am trying to store all unique words in `ArrayList` as unique objects and increment the occurrence of the word object if the word repeats in the text file.

```
Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(textfile));
ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();
while (file.hasNext()) {

    Word w = new Word(fileWord);

    if (words.contains(w)) {
        w.increaseCount();
    } else {
        words.add(w);
    }
}
```

Word Class is;

```
public class Word {
    private String text;
    private int count;

    public Word(String wordText) {
        text = wordText;
    }

    public void increaseCount() {
        count += 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object wordToCompare) {
        if (wordToCompare instanceof Word) {
            Word castedWord = (Word) wordToCompare;
            if (castedWord.text.equals(this.text)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return text.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Unique words get added to the `ArrayList`, but my count does not increment. How to increment the count

Comment: You should increment the count of `Word` in the list with same value as `w` instead of changing the count of `w`.

Comment: That is where i am confused. How to increment the count of that word thats already in list. Can you please tell me how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this statement in your code;

```
while (file.hasNext()) {

    Word w = new Word(fileWord);

    if (words.contains(w)) {
        w.increaseCount(); // Here's what goes wrong.
    } else {
        words.add(w);
    }
}
```

You're invoking the function `increaseCount()` on newly created object and that would get replaced during the next iteration, and you lost the reference. But the actual object is in the `ArrayList` and you should increase the value of that object. So, I would say, your code should be changed like this;

```
Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(textfile));
ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();
while (file.hasNext()) {

    Word w = new Word(fileWord);

    if (words.contains(w)) {
        words.get(words.indexOf(w)).increaseCount(); // Note the change here.
    } else {
        w.increaseCount(); // This is for the first occurrence as 'count' is 0 initially.
        words.add(w);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you create new instance of Word in the loop.
When the array contains the newly created Word, you increase the count for it, not the existing instance which already added to the array before.
Consider to use Map for the problem, the key is the word and the value is the count.

```
package example.stackoverflow;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class WordCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> sourceList = Arrays.asList("ABC", "XYZ", "HGK", "ABC", "PWT", "HGK", "ABC");

        Map<String, Integer> wordCount = new HashMap();

        for (String word : sourceList) {
            if (wordCount.get(word) != null) {
                wordCount.put(word, wordCount.get(word) +1);
            } else {
                wordCount.put(word, 1);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(wordCount);//output: {ABC=3, XYZ=1, PWT=1, HGK=2}
    }

}
```

Comment: Consider to use "Set", should it be "Map"? And it will be great if you can provide a simple example.

Comment: @samabcde thank you, I just realized and edit the comment

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer:

```
    Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(textfile));
    ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();
    while (file.hasNext()) {

        Word w = new Word(fileWord);

        if (words.contains(w)) {
            w.increaseCount();
            int index = words.indexOf(w);
            Word w1 = words.get(index);
            w1.increaseCount();
            words.set(index, w1);
        } else {
            words.add(w);
        }
    }
```